# How do I create a .db file from an sql script?

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm creating a gui in python to manipulate stored records and I have the mysql script to set up the database and enter all information. How do I get from the mysql script to the .db file so that python can access and manipulate it?

Comment: do you mean...create a database from sql files??

Comment: I have a .sql file created with mysql. I meant to create a .db file since python requires a .db file. It will not accept .sql file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db` files are SQLite databases most of the time. What you are trying to do is converting a dumped MySQL database into an SQLite database. Doing this is not trivial, as I think both dialects are not compatible. If the input is simple enough, you can try running each part of it using an SQLite connection in your Python script. If it uses more complex features, you may want to actually connect to a (filled) MySQL database and fetch the data from there, inserting it back into a local SQLite file.